# Recover Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, boot

ALL,

I have a dual-boot laptop with Windows 7 and Linux (Gentoo).

Unfortunately, right now I can't boot into Windows. It looks like for some reason the MBR for Windows partition got corrupted.

Is there a way to recover the Windows install keeping all the data (including Linux install) or the machine will have to be rebuilt?

I'm hoping it is just a Windows Boot Loader.

TIA!!

[EDIT]

I'm also checking if my GRUB2 configuration is correct.

[[/EDIT]

Comment: What are the symptoms? Are you booting in UEFI mode or legacy mode?

Comment: @gronostaj, UEFI, what do you mean by `symptoms`? In the GRUB menu selecting `Windows`, is not going to boot OS - instead it is stating the process of installing Windows.

Comment: Please add that information to the question ([edit] it). If possible please include a photo of the installation screen that shows up.

Comment: @Igor what do you mean - "process of installing Windows" ?? Win can't be install just like that !! Also you can access ntfs drives from Linux , so copy and save it somewhere safe !! There are many tutorials/q-a on how to repair win mbr - follow them and see if it helps ; there is boot repair tool in Linux {not sure about gentoo but comes with Linux mint live ISO } to troubleshoot problems like this - try that !! Also is your csm mode enabled ?? Also win 7 doesn't support UEFI fully - so best would be to switch to win 10 !!